# routing already in table when trying to add additional route to the same net

Tags: freebsd, routing, openvpn, pfsense

I have the following table

```
$ netstat -r -4 | grep 33.0
192.168.33.0/24    192.168.29.4       UGS      ovpns5
```

I would like to add additional route to the same network and get

```
$ route add -net 192.168.33.0/24 192.168.27.2
add net 192.168.33.0: gateway 192.168.27.2 fib 0: route already in table
```

Why? Isn't it possible to have two routes to the same net?

I can do `route change` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

When the kernel is looking for a route for an outbound packet, it wants to find a single answer: if there are multiple matches, it doesn't know which one to pick.

[This thread](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2003-August/014884.html) on the `freebsd-questions` mailing list covers the same question, and suggests solving the problem by "splitting" one of the routes to create two more-specific routes:

> The trick to adding a backup default route is to split 'default'
> into 2 different and more specific subnets:
>
> ```
> # route add 0.0.0.0 PRIMARY_GW -netmask 127.0.0.0
> # route add 127.0.0.0 PRIMARY_GW -netmask 127.0.0.0
> # route add default SECONDARY_GW
> ```
>
> Now that default is split into 2 different smaller subnets than
> 'default' they will be the preferred route.  If your interface
> that connects PRIMARY_GW goes down, the first 2 routes will be
> removed, leave your backup 'default' gateway to take affect.

In your case, if you want the existing route (via 192.168.29.4) to be
used when it's available, you would want something like this:

```
route add -net 192.168.33.0/25 192.168.29.4
route add -net 192.168.33.128/25 192.168.29.4
route add -net 192.168.33.0/24 192.168.27.2
```

Because the kernel always prefers the most specific route, this will
use 192.168.29.4 as the gateway as long as the `ovpns5` interface is
available. If that interfaces goes down, the routes will be removed
and the kernel will start using the `192.168.27.2` gateway.

---

If you're hoping to load balance between the two connections, you're
looking for equal-cost multipath routing (ecmp), and I'm unclear on
the state of support for that with FreeBSD.

Comment: I was thinking that load balancing should work out of the box with any TCP/IP stack. I can't imagine, that protocol assumes that all networks should have only one router and only one route.

Comment: The *kernel* assumes that all endpoints have a single unique route; this isn't really a "protocol" thing. As I said, there is support for load-balanced routing; I know it's available in Linux, but I'm not familiar with FreeBSD networking, and the searches I made when posting the answer were somewhat inconclusive.

Comment: How is it working in global internet? I can tracerout to some site and see route is different from day to day. Is this done mostlly with `ecmp`?

Comment: The internet at large uses dynamic routing protocols rather than static route tables.